# Mapping vertex 0-7 to 3D points?

Tags: c#, sorting, vector, vertices

I have 8 vertices of a cube that are simply indexes. I want to get every vertex's respective point of where it would be in a normalized cube. In the following diagram, assume that +x is to the right, +y is up, and +z is coming out of the screen. (vertices 2, 3, 6, and 7 are in front, if it's hard to see).

[image: Polygonise]

<sup>(ignore the edge indexes)</sup>

Here's what I have:

```
for (int v = 0; v < 8; v++) {
    float x, y, z;

    if(v < 4)                                    y = -1;
    else                                         y = +1;
    if(v == 1 || v == 2 || v == 5 || v == 6)     x = +1;
    else                                         x = -1;
    if(v == 2 || v == 3 || v == 6 || v == 7)     z = +1;
    else                                         z = -1;
}
```

Is there a more logical way to do this, without so many logical ORs?

Comment: Which language are you using? Please add the corresponding tag!

Comment: @UliKöhler Sorry. I thought it wouldn't matter that much.

Comment: It could matter, depending on the solution ;-) Quick tip: I'd try to use lookup tables

Comment: Sorry for the frequent edits of my answer, I now added a full code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookup tables.
LUTs tend to be quite efficient, but some people find them counter-intuitive.

```
for (int v = 0; v < 8; v++) {
    int[] lutX = new int[] {-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int[] lutY = new int[] {-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int[] lutZ = new int[] {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1};
    float x = lutX[v];
    float y = lutY[v];
    float z = lutZ[v];
}
```

Usually you should declare them statically outside your function.

You can deduce the LUTs from your OR-based logic by a logic like this:

```
If for v==0, the OR-logic adds 1 to X, set lutX[0] to 1.
Else set lutX[0] to -1
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood the question. I'm trying to map the 8 vertices to their corresponding points on the cube. The edges are not given.

Comment: @DantheMan Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm not sure how to understand it. To my understanding, my code example is a full conversion of your code example from above. I didnt really check your logic to be honest.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I didn't understand the other code about the lines.. I thought that you were referring to the edges on the figure. Thanks. This works perfectly.

Comment: @DantheMan Sure, happy to help. Please re-check the LUT values before using it productively ;-)

Comment: @DantheMan I added a note on how to deduce the LUTs from the OR-based logic, just in case it isn't obvious.

Comment: you will want to mve the array definition `lutx` out side the loop, right?

Comment: @ja72 Usually, yes (for efficiency and style reasons). You want the LUT to be initialized once (e.g. on startup), and then used multiple times. You don't want it to be initialized on any function calls. (Same goes for lutY and lutZ, of course)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one liner:

```
float x = 2*((v/2)%2)-1, y = 2*(v/4)-1, z = 2*(v%2)-1;
```

Test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.Print("{0,3} {1,3},{2,3},{3,3}", "v", "x", "y", "z");
    for(int v=0; v<8; v++)
    {
        float x=2*((v/2)%2)-1, y=2*(v/4)-1, z=2*(v%2)-1;

        Debug.Print("{0,3} {1,3},{2,3},{3,3}", v, x, y, z);
    }
}
```

result:

```
v   x,  y,  z
0  -1, -1, -1
1  -1, -1,  1
2   1, -1, -1
3   1, -1,  1
4  -1,  1, -1
5  -1,  1,  1
6   1,  1, -1
7   1,  1,  1
```